# Qemu-KVM Help: Can't blacklist one of two GPU's of same model

Tags: nvidia, games, intel, kvm-virtualization, pci

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Multiheaded-NVIDIA-Gaming-using-Ubuntu-14-04-KVM-585/) to make a Windows KVM system for games, I have two GTX 760's, but I need to black list only one of them.  According to this tutorial, if I put in the ID to black list the GPU, it will black list both of them.  My goal is to have one GPU for Ubuntu so I can play games that are already available for Linux, like Dying Light, and I want one for Windows to play Windows exclusive games like Final Fantasy 14.  I could blacklist both cards, and have SLI support on the Windows partition, though, but I want that to be a last resort since not many games run very well on Intel HD4600, and I would have to go through so much trouble uninstalling Nvidia drivers and getting Intel drivers working.

[image]

Comment: What's the output of `ls /sys/bus/pci/devices/` and which one of the two do you want to disable?

Comment: have you eventually succeeded? if yes, how? I've got the same issue :/

Answer (score 1):

I spent a month trying to do this. Finally I found how, just run this:

```
echo "vfio-pci" | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:03:00.0/driver_override
echo "vfio-pci" | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:03:00.1/driver_override
sudo modprobe -i vfio-pci
```